# I am not getting 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0' update for Google play services in sdk

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-pay

I have updated my Android SDK completely still I am not getting update for Google play services version 8.4.0 i.e. 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0' like mentioned in the link for implementing Android Pay https://developers.google.com/android-pay/android/tutorial.

Whenever I add this line : "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0'" in build.gradle, I got following error : Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue is been fixed after installing all the latest versions of build tools and other updates, Now I got updates of this library and its working fine.

Answer (score 6):

After encountering the error you will be given three choices by Android Studio

*Install repository and sync project*

*Show in File*

*Show in Project Structure dialog*

You just have to click '**Install repository and sync project**'. After that, it worked fine for me.

Comment: This should be marked as answer @mithil instead of accepting this as correct answer you posted same thing and marked as answer, i wish you would give credit where its due.

Comment: Worked for me. Had the exact same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me too. I guess it just wasn't available yet.

But the following implementation is now working for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: try doing it by a lower version, 8.3.0 or jus compile as:" compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'"

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to make an App using Android Studio and had the same issue.
Resolved it by starting Android Studio as administrator on my windows machine and letting gradle resync (just rebuild the project).

hope anyone finds this useful. ;)